# How to get similar google java formatting in intellij and with maven

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, google-java-format

I'd like to have the google java formatting in my IDE (using the [google-java-format plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8527-google-java-format) for IntelliJ or something else if that's not the best way to do...) and be able to check with maven that formatting is OK (in a GitHub workflow for example). I tried the [spotless plugin](https://github.com/diffplug/spotless/tree/main/plugin-maven#google-java-format).

Unfortunately for the moment, the results are completely different if I use one or the other (imports order, parameters in methods, ...). I use the AOSP format to get 4 spaces indentation in both case.

Here is my spotless config:

```xml
               <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.diffplug.spotless</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spotless-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.30.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>check</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <java>
                            <googleJavaFormat>
                                <version>1.7</version>
                                <style>AOSP</style>
                            </googleJavaFormat>
                            <removeUnusedImports />
                            <licenseHeader>
                                <file>../license-header</file>
                            </licenseHeader>
                        </java>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
```

Am I missing something? Aren't they supposed to work with google format (which should be the same...)? Actually I'm not sure Intellij is applying the formatting from the google plugin and not from my other code style configuration. "Enable google-java-format" is checked in the settings, but how to be sure?

Comment: You could try using other formatting integrations instead of spotless - https://github.com/google/google-java-format/tree/master#third-party-integrations or discuss this issue with the google-java-format plugin developer directly at https://github.com/google/google-java-format/issues